# Как зафиксировать положение оси на графике Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, диаграммы, виджет, d3.js

У менять есть график, который визуализирует данные по дням.
Тип графика: AreaChart, библиотека: Recharts (http://recharts.org)

Проблема:
При изменении параметров, по которым отрисовывается график, сам график перерисовывается и позиция оси X немного меняется. Изменение позиции оси выглядит очень убого, как будто вёрстка всего виджета ломается.
(Позиция оси изменяется, т.к. к ней привязаны даты, а я меняю период).

Есть какой-то способ зафиксировать саму ось так, чтобы линия оси не прыгала? 
"Тики" пусть меняются на оси как как хотят, это естественное поведение, но прыгающая ось выглядит как ломающаяся вёрстка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте завернуть в <ResponsiveContainer>

Comment: это уже сделано